# Is it ok to use TouchAction.press & waitaction which are deprecated, in Appium

Tags: webview, automation, automated-tests, appium, appium-ios

Currently I'm writing a Appium script for an ios ionic app and I used the following method for the swipe functionality.

```html
public void swipeHorizontal(AppiumDriver<MobileElement> driver, double startPercentage, double finalPercentage, int duration) throws Exception {
    Dimension size = driver.manage().window().getSize();
    int width = (int) (size.width/2);
    int startPoint = (int) (size.getHeight()*startPercentage);
    int endpoint = (int) (size.getHeight()*finalPercentage);
    new TouchAction(driver).press(width,startPoint).waitAction(Duration.ofSeconds(0)).moveTo(width,endpoint).release().perform();
   }
```

in the above method the word press, waitAction & moveto are cut off with the message "press(int,int)" is deprecated. Similarly to waitAction & moveto as well. Is it ok to use such deprecated methods or am I doing something wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Anytime you see that something is "deprecated" it means that while it is still technically supported, it is only supported so that existing (legacy) apps will continue to function, and that something new, and supposedly better, has replaced it, and that you should instead use the new method.

There is now a swipe method in Appium, and it makes things a lot simpler.  Here's my code using swipe:

```
/**
 * This method performs a swipe on an Android element
 * @author Bill Hileman
 * @param element - an Android element, i.e. an EditView, TextView, etc.
 * @param locator - a verbal description of the element for logging purposes
 * @param direction - a value of type SwipeElementDirection
 * @param duration - time in milliseconds for the swipe to complete
 */
public void swipe(AndroidElement element, String locator, SwipeElementDirection direction, int duration) {

    try {
        element.swipe(direction, duration);
    } catch (NullPointerException | NoSuchElementException e) {
        System.err.println("Unable to locate element '" + locator + "'");
        fail();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.err.println("Unable to swipe " + direction.toString() + " element '" + locator + "'");
        e.printStackTrace();
        fail();
    }

}
```